# High CPU usage on Pong clone

Tags: c++, opengl, collision-detection, efficiency

I just made my first game, a clone of Pong, using OpenGL and C++. But its using ~50% of the CPU, which I guess is very high for a game like this. How can I improve that? Can you please look up my code and tell me what all things I am doing wrong? Any feedback is welcome.

<strike>http://pastebin.com/L5zE3axh</strike>

http://pastebin.com/rMJ6PG9k

Also it would be extremely helpful if you give some general points on how to develop games in OpenGL efficiently..

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**

I forced VSync on from CCC, and now the game just shows ~5% CPU usage, except when my own wait() method is called (my fault). I can solve that...but now another problem has come, the game feels very choppy and its not smooth after forcing on VSync.
Maybe tearing because of single buffering?

Any ideas?

**EDIT 2:**

Was calling the display callback twice from my idle function, using display() and glutPostRedisplay()! Also, changed the mode to GLUT_DOUBLE, now Fraps works on it..

One more thing! This game is working fine with VSync on (or forced) at 60fps.. but when I turn off VSync, it goes too fast. Do I have an option to turn on VSync? Or is any any other way?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Questions that require people to look at large pastes of code and essentially find problems for you is not a good fit for this site. When you identify the problem, you can ask the specific question and we can assist you.

Comment: Will keep that in mind!

Comment: @JustinSkiles I just edited my question, its now more specific.. can you have a look a it please?

Comment: hi max, your Edit2 "it goes too fast when turn off VSync" is because your gameplay depends on how fast your framerate is. see [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4494/thread-runs-faster-on-a-faster-processor-how-to-control-thread-speed) and in particular the Fix Your Timestep article

Comment: @Jimmy Thank you! I solved it by rendering a frame, then Sleep(1ms) for the rest of the time, until the total time is 1000/FPS milliseconds :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've implemented your own wait function that keeps the CPU running a small loop instead of letting it process other threads.

Call a sleep() method instead. It comes in various styles and flavors (depending on platform) or, if you want to keep your code portable, you could use [Boost Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread.html) e.g

```
 boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::seconds(1) );
```

Comment: Hi, you were right. But, earlier the game was using ~50% of the CPU even on the main menu. What I did then is forced VSync on from CCC. It now gives me only ~5% of CPU usage, and goes to 50% only when my wait() is called. And a new problem has arisen, the game feels very choppy, and the flow is not smooth. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: You can replace your wait function with the code that lithander suggested. Also, take a look at [glutTimerFunc](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html), it might solve your problem without adding another library such as _boost_.